# Configure tomcat apache to execute a sub-directory as first page

Tags: apache, tomcat, web.xml

Currently suppose xyz.com executes webapp ROOT.
How can I configure my tomcat; so that by default  xyz.com takes me to xyz.com/abc [abc is a directory inside ROOT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have JSTL set up, you can redirect from ROOT/index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:redirect url='abc' />
```

Or use scriptlet from ROOT/index.jsp:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("http://xyz.com/abc"); %>
```